# Spring boot issue when deployed on to Mesos dcos having multiple microservices

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, haproxy, mesos, dcos

I am new to spring boot and have recently encountered a weird issue. My application which already has a context path runs smoothly on the localhost with a URL like "localhost:port/contextpath/dashboard". But when I try to deploy it on Mesosphere DCOS, it produces an error. Since the mesos server has multiple microservices, each service is separated by a service name,so the service got deployed onto a path like "server.com/servicename/contextpath/dashboard". However, internally the relative mapping is such that any internal reference, be it a navigation like or request mapping of controller ends up something like "server.com/contextpath/dashboard" which misses out on the service name and hence doesn't work.

Comment: `produces an error`. So we should guess what error has occurred?

Comment: my bad,503 service not available error occurs.

Comment: @ayushprashar Add this information into your question please so other people could see.